# How to convert json values to keys? Basically I want to use value of one key as a "key" and value of other as value

Tags: java, json, api, rest, jackson2

I am writing API in java spring boot. I am consuming below json as response from another API

```json
[
  {
  "item": "Apple",
  "count": 30
  },
  {
  "item": "Orange",
  "count": 10
  },
  {
  "item": "Guava",
  "count": 4
  }
]
```

I want to convert this to

```json
{
  "Apple": 30,
  "Orange": 10,
  "Guava": 4
}
```

What is the simplest & efficient way to do this?

Comment: BTW, note that simplicity and efficiency are typically opposite to each other. For example, the most efficient way is to use the stream/event/token-oriented parsing rather than the object mapping, but typically it takes a bit more code to be written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class to hold an item

```
public record Item {
    String item;
    int count;
}
```

Deserialise to a `List<Item>` using your favourite json library (mine is Jackson).

The collect to a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream().collect(toMap(Item::getItem, Item::getCount));
```